# Java sockets server help

Tags: java, android, sockets

Hi there im very new to java programing and am really stuck getting a socket server and client working how i want.

The problem im having is...

server:

Im looking at the output from the client and once client prints "TIME" the server will return a message eg "the time is...". The server does this but not straight away it seems to send it on the second time you send a message from the client.

Is this becuase the client is not connected all the time maybe ?

Im pretty sure this method is wrong can anyone give me some advice.

Any help would be great .

Luke

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class MyServer {

public static void main(String[] args){
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
Socket socket = null;
DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

try {
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
System.out.println("Listening :8888");
} catch (IOException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
 }

 while(true){
 try {
socket = serverSocket.accept();
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));


dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
System.out.println("ip: " + socket.getInetAddress());
System.out.println("message: " + dataInputStream.readUTF());
dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Hello!");



try{
 String line = in.readLine();


 if (line.contains("TIME")){
  dataOutputStream.writeUTF("TIME IS.....");  // ITS HERE THE PROBLEM MAY BE ?

  {


    } catch (IOException e){
    System.out.println("Read failed");
    System.exit(1);
          }




 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally{
  if( socket!= null){
    try {
     socket.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
}

if( dataInputStream!= null){
 try {
  dataInputStream.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
}

if( dataOutputStream!= null){
 try {
  dataOutputStream.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
   }
   }
   }
   }
```

**The Android Client**

*UPDATE* , i think the problem is with the client only being connected when you send a message. How do i have a reading loop in here that wont affect when i send data out from the client.

```
package com.exercise.AndroidClient;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidClient extends Activity {

EditText textOut;
TextView textIn;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);

 textOut = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textout);
 Button buttonSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
 textIn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textin);
 buttonSend.setOnClickListener(buttonSendOnClickListener);
 }

 Button.OnClickListener buttonSendOnClickListener
 = new Button.OnClickListener(){

 @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 Socket socket = null;
 DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
 DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

 try {
 socket = new Socket("192.168.1.101", 8888);
 dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
 dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
 dataOutputStream.writeUTF(textOut.getText().toString());
 textIn.setText(dataInputStream.readUTF());
 }  catch (UnknownHostException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
if (socket != null){
try {
socket.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

if (dataOutputStream != null){
try {
dataOutputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

if (dataInputStream != null){
try {
dataInputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
}};
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After the `dataOutputStream.writeUTF()` line, write `dataOutputStream.flush();`. That will send all the data through.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you’re reading from the stream to output the message.

```
    System.out.println("message: " + dataInputStream.readUTF());
```

So the command has been removed from the stream when you try to run

```
    String line = in.readLine();
```

You should try to read the command from the stream into a variable before outputting the message and then check if that string contains "TIME".

Also why use two different methods to read from the stream? You could just use the BufferedReader and discard DataInputStream. You could as well use PrintWriter instead of DataOutputStream.

Something like this:

```
    out = new PrintWriter( socket.getOutputStream(), true );
```

and then:

```
    out.println( "Time is..." );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to reply . This does help tho it is not what im after . It seems that my client is connected only when it wants to send data hence it wont recieve the data after the client has sent "time". I think i need the client to be looping waiting for incomming data. Will this not work as i get feeling sockets cant transmit and recieve at the same time ? cheers again

Comment: Yes you have to loop the client as well. You send something to the server an immediately read from the stream. This will wait for incoming data. Good luck ;)

Comment: Ive now put up my basic client code , can you have a quick look and maybe suggest how i can adapt this code to have a reading loop in there and still be able to write data out. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: I would put the whole `try..catch` block inside a `while(true)` loop.